# Two DistributionChart results in single plot

Tags: plotting, charts

I have two sets of data that live on different scales, but I would like to plot them together to show the distributions of values side-by-side. Is there a way to add a second y-axis on the right that corresponds to (and scales) that respective data properly.

For example:

```
DistributionChart[{RandomReal[{0, 1.5}, 1000], 
  RandomReal[{0, 0.01}, 1000]}]
```

generates a squished distribution for the second variable. I'd like a second y axis on the right that goes from say (0,0.01).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
{data1, data2} = {RandomReal[{0, 1.5}, 1000], RandomReal[{0, 0.01}, 1000]};
```

You can [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) `data2` to have the same scale as `data1` and construct the correct frame ticks for the right edge using `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
DistributionChart[{data1, Rescale[data2, MinMax @ data2, MinMax @ data1]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
     Charting`FindTicks[MinMax @ data1, MinMax @ data2][## & @@ MinMax[data1]]},
    {None, None}}]
```

[image]

To get the correct tooltips for `data2`, we can extract the tooltip from the `DistributionChart` with original `data2` as input and use it as the tooltip for the rescaled `data2`:

```
tooltip2 = Cases[DistributionChart[{data2}], Tooltip[_, t_] :> t, All][[1]];
DistributionChart[{data1, 
    Tooltip[Rescale[data2, MinMax @ data2, MinMax @ data1], tooltip2]},
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
      Charting`FindTicks[ MinMax@data1, MinMax@data2][## & @@ MinMax[data1]]}, 
    {None, None}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use  logarithmic scaling:

```
 DistributionChart[{data1,data2}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, nice catch with tooltips. I didn't even notice the scaling issue until you edited the change.